# Writing a single table value in sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a Python 2.7 project, and I'm using (and learning) sqlite3.

How do I save a variable from python to a single existing column and row in an sqlite3 database?

Comment: You do it with SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say you have a table named "records" with the column "X", and each entry has a different "X" value, and let's say you want to change the value of column "Y". You would use this SQL query:

```
cursor.execute("update records set y = ? where x = ?", (y, x))
```

Comment: 'UPDATE records SET Y = y WHERE X = x' is a query.  The execute function call inserts y and x for the question marks in the order they appear and passes the query to the database.

Comment: @Opieus: a query is a question. UPDATE asks no question and returns no answer. Please don't perpetuate sloppy terminology.

Comment: Why didn't you post that in response to the answer instead of seeming to ask a question?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not familiar with SQL, you could try using an ORM, which maps DB tables to python classes and objects. I am a big fan of Storm. You can find it here:

https://storm.canonical.com/